# Reading Characters from Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I want to extract the IP address from the following String:

106.220.155.36 - - [29/Sep/2015:09:51:52 -0400] "GET /tutorial/grammar/LL/images/llparsetable.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14284

To do this, I decided to read the string one character at a time. I tried the following code:

```
public static String uniqueIP(String line){
        String IP = "";

        while(line.next() != " "){
            IP = IP + line.next();
        }
        return IP;
    }
```

However, the next method doesn't work. Is there some other method I can use?

Comment: what's `line.next()` ?

Comment: A String is more or less an Array of Character

Comment: Where did you get the `next` method, some blog I'm guessing? Help yourself by looking at the `String` Javadoc; if you're writing Java code (apparently), Javadoc is the first place to look for help, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: "However, the next method doesn't work" this looks like another case for [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your string structure will be always the same you can split it by "- -"

```
String s = "106.220.155.36 - - [29/Sep/2015:09:51:52 -0400] "GET /tutorial/grammar/LL/images/llparsetable.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14284"

String ip = s.split("- -")[0].trim();
```